# Meaning of all amounts populated in Swap event

Tags: erc-20

What does it mean when an erc20 swap event has both an amount0_in and amount1_in?

Are they receiving both tokens in return?  Why does this make any sense?

Comment: Could you please provide more details? Each swap-like Defi protocol has own specifics and the contract realisation could greatly vary.

Comment: @valentinmk im afraid I don't have anymore knowledge on this topic to elaborate.  Maybe you could start an answer and Ill expand after that?  Or do you have any specific questions?

Comment: Could you show us where you saw the "amount0_in" and "amount1_in"? Those values could mean different things depending on the context in which they were used. So having some sample code to understand the context would be helpful.